# Facebook/Twitter Auto Posts Allowed with oAuth and ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, twitter

Does anyone know (or tried successfully) if you can write a .net page/script that will **automatically post** to a "corporate" facebook or twitter account **behind the scenes**.  In other words the twitter and fb accounts are the website owner's who's a realtor.  When an update comes in via an XML feed and updates the listing, the code should then post/tweet something like: "123 Main Street Just Lowered Price from $123.00 to $100.00 http:[linkbithere]" **without any interaction** from the realtor.

Everything I've seen lately due to the oAuth settings always seems to require some type of user intervention.  If that's the case and there's no way around it...great...I just need to be able to point my client to some sites where they can verify that.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. I haven't done it for twitter, but I have for Facebook. For facebook you just need to get the stream_publish and offline_access permissions for the user and then you will get an oauth token that will allow you to publish without the user's interaction. I would suggest using the [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com) on Codeplex to connect with Facebook. Twitter has the same capabilities. I don't know exactly the permissions you need for twitter, but it will be similar to Facebook. After you get the token for each service, you will just save it in a database or something and reuse it each time you need to make a new post.